# Свежесозданный виртуальный хост на свежеустановленном apache2 в Ubuntu, WSL пишет: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. Почему?

Tags: ubuntu, apache, apache2, lamp, wsl

Установил в Ubuntu apache2 со всем, что входит в сборку LAMP.
Команда

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

показывает, что сервер работает. При обращении на localhost приветственная страница в браузере открывалась.

Создал виртуальный хост в дополнение к `var/www/html`.

Конфиг такой:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName eshop1.local
    ServerAlias www.eshop1.local

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/eshop1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
 
# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

Это просто копия конфига по умолчанию с данными для сайта в папке `/var/www/eshop1`.

Активировал сайт `sudo a2ensite eshop1.local.conf`.

Теперь в браузере ввожу `eshop1.local` - ошибка:

```
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN
```

**Что обнаружил**:

1. при обращении на `localhost/test.html` теперь вместо приветственной страницы открывается файл test.html, лежащий в `var/www/eshop1.local`
2. пинг на `eshop1.local` дает такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В error.log последние записи такие (я их не понимаю, но последнее, что делал обращался к eshop1.local):

```
[Sat Jun 17 18:05:12.343955 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20912] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 17 18:05:12.344030 2023] [core:notice] [pid 20912] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat Jun 17 18:51:30.448060 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 20912] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Jun 17 18:51:47.522118 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 21565] AH00163: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Jun 17 18:51:47.522265 2023] [core:notice] [pid 21565] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Подскажите, почему не работает созданный хост. Всю голову сломал(((

Comment: Потому что у WSL-виртуалки своя отдельная сеть, которая не имеет ничего общего с тем 127.0.0.1 который вы пингуете?

Comment: @andreymal всегда на порту localhost сайты из wsl работали. Кладешь в нужную папку на wsl код, по адресу localhost она отображается

Comment: У вас WSL2? Во второй версии линукс работает в выделенной подсетке. [Поменяйте тип WSL на первую версию](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/164318-how-set-linux-distribution-version-wsl-1-wsl-2-windows-10-a.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

новый созданный хост заработал после того, как в host файл операционной системы добавил такую запись:
127.0.0.1 eshop1.local
::1 eshop1.local
вместо просто
127.0.0.1 eshop1.local

что значит вот это ::1  я так и не понял, но заработало)

Comment: `::1` это IPv6-адрес локалхоста